# Apache Hive - get the last day of the previous month

Tags: hive

Using Apache Hive, I am trying to get the last day of the previous month using the system current_date.  I can find the current months last day using last_day(current_date) but I need the previous month.  I have tried using add_months(-1) and date_add to the current_date but that gives me an error saying the function(s) do not exist.

expecting the previous month's last day

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below and it is working fine.

```
select last_day(add_months(current_date, -1));
```

[Ambari screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ireZt.png)

If this doesn't solve your issue, please share the query, error and Hive version